# fetch() returns : warning: block supersedes default value argument

Tags: ruby, arrays

Why do I get this warning and what it means?

```
a = [1,3,5]
a.fetch(0) #=> 1
a.fetch(0,0) #=> 1

a.fetch(22) { "out of range" } #=> out of range
a.fetch(0,0) { "out of range" } #=> returns 1 with warning: block supersedes default value argument
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-fetch) accepts at most 2 parameters.

> - fetch(index) → obj
> - fetch(index, default) → obj      # <-----
> - fetch(index) { |index| block } → obj

You are passing more arguments than that at the last setence.

Comment: isn't (0,0) is an index, thus a single parameter?

Comment: @Bala, the first 0 is argument for `index`. the second 0 is argument for `default`.

Answer (score 2):

You are supplying two default values to `fetch` in `a.fetch(0,0) { "out of range" }`

1. The second `0` in `fetch(0,0)`.
2. The return value from the block.

The warning tells you that the return value of the block is used as default rather than the default value you supplied.